# Calling NetValidatePasswordPolicy from C# always returns Password Must Change

Tags: c#, com, active-directory, interop

We have a mvc application that is using Active Directory to authenticate our users. We are leveraging `System.DirectoryServices` and using the `PricipalContext` to authenticate:

`_principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, pass, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);`

However this method only returns a bool and we want to return better messages or even redirect the user to a password reset screen for instances like:

1. The user is locked out of their account.
2. The users password is expired.
3. The user needs to change their password at next login.

So if the user fails to login we call `NetValidatePasswordPolicy` to see why the user was not able to log in. This seemed to work well but we realized that this method was only returning `NET_API_STATUS.NERR_PasswordMustChange` no matter what the state of the Active Directory user was.

The only example I have found with this same problem comes from a Sublime Speech plugin [here](https://github.com/Mozillion/SublimeSpeech/blob/master/lib/pywin32bit/win32/Demos/NetValidatePasswordPolicy.py). The code I am using is as follows:

```cs
var outputPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
var inputArgs = new NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_CHANGE_INPUT_ARG { PasswordMatched = false, UserAccountName = username };
inputArgs.ClearPassword = Marshal.StringToBSTR(password);

var inputPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
inputPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(inputArgs));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(inputArgs, inputPointer, false);

using (new ComImpersonator(adImpersonatingUserName, adImpersonatingDomainName, adImpersonatingPassword))
{
    var status = NetValidatePasswordPolicy(serverName, IntPtr.Zero, NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE.NetValidateAuthentication, inputPointer, ref outputPointer);

    if (status == NET_API_STATUS.NERR_Success)
    {
        var outputArgs = (NET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG)Marshal.PtrToStructure(outputPointer, typeof(NET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG));
        return outputArgs.ValidationStatus;
    }
    else
    {
       //fail
    }   
}
```

The code always succeeds so why is the value of `outputArgs.ValidationStatus` the same result every time regardless of the state of the Active Directory user?

Comment: have you tried GetLastError() after ValidateCredentials()? then you can use the error code to determine the message, for example 1907 is "user must reset password", 1330 is "password expired" and so on... another option I can think about is [Logon](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LogonUser.html) instead of ValidateCredentials and then GetLastError()

Comment: I looked over the source code of ValidateCredentials(), the method use LADP, if there is an error code the method will throw exception, then catch the exception and return false. so GetLastError will probably work. I also saw there are some special error codes for active directory.

Comment: We didnt want to use the LogonUser method because we are using Directory Services to logon. If the user mistypes their password we would try to logon, fail, and then logon to see why it failed. This would give two failed logon attempts for every one attempt by the user. I will look into the GetLastError() but it seems odd that the ValidateCredentials would return 1907 every time and then force the developer to look at the GetLastError() to get the actual code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will break the answer to this question into three different sections:

1. The Current Problem With Your Methodology
2. The Issues With Recommended Solutions both Online, and in this Thread
3. The Solution

**The current problem with your methodology.**

`NetValidatePasswordPolicy` requires its `InputArgs` parameter to take in a pointer to a structure, and the structure you pass in depend on the `ValidationType` your're passing in.  In this case, you are passing `NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE.NetValidateAuthentication`, which requires an InputArgs of `NET_VALIDATE_AUTHENTICATION_INPUT_ARG` but you're passing in a pointer to `NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_CHANGE_INPUT_ARG`.

Furthermore, you are attempting to assign a "currentPassword' type of value to the `NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_CHANGE_INPUT_ARG` structure.

However, there's a bigger fundamental proble to the use of `NetValidatePasswordPolicy` and that is that you are trying to use this function to validate passwords in Active Directory, but this is not what it is used for.  `NetValidatePasswordPolicy` is used to allow applications to validate against a authentication database provided by the application.

There's more information about `NetValidatePasswordPolicy` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**The issues with recommended solutions both online, and in this thread**

Various articles online recommend using the `LogonUser` function found in `AdvApi32.dll` but this implementation carries its own set of issues:

The first is that `LogonUser` validates against a local cache, and that means that you will not get immediate accurate information about the account, unless you use the "Network" mode.

The second is that using `LogonUser` on a Web application, in my opinion is a bit hacky, as it is designed for desktop applications running on client machines.  However, considering the limitations provided Microsoft if `LogonUser` gives desired results, I don't see why it shouldn't be used - barring the caching issues.

Another issue with `LogonUser` is that how well it works for your use case depends on how your server is configured, for example:  There are some particular permissions that need to be enabled on the domain you're authenticating against that need to be in place for 'Network' logon type to work.

More information about `LogonUser` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also, `GetLastError()` should not be used, `GetLastWin32Error()` should be used instead, as it is not safe to use `GetLastError()`.

More information about `GetLastWin32Error()` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

**The solution.**

In order to get an accurate error code from Active Directory, without any caching issues and straight from directory services, this is what needs to be done:  rely on COMException coming back from AD when there's an issue with the account, because ultimately, errors is what you're looking for.

First, here's how you trigger an error from Active Directory on authentication of a current user name and a password:

```
public LdapBindAuthenticationErrors AuthenticateUser(string domain, string username, string password, string ouString)
    {
        // The path (ouString) should not include the user in the directory, otherwise this will always return true
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ouString, username, password);

        try
        {
            // Bind to the native object, this forces authentication.
            var obj = entry.NativeObject;
            var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry) { Filter = string.Format("({0}={1})", ActiveDirectoryStringConstants.SamAccountName, username) };
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            if (result != null)
            {
                return LdapBindAuthenticationErrors.OK;
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException c)
        {
            LdapBindAuthenticationErrors ldapBindAuthenticationError = -1;
                    // These LDAP bind error codes are found in the "data" piece (string) of the extended error message we are evaluating, so we use regex to pull that string
                    if (Regex.Match(c.ExtendedErrorMessage, @" data (?<ldapBindAuthenticationError>[a-f0-9]+),").Success)
                    {
                        string errorHexadecimal = match.Groups["ldapBindAuthenticationError"].Value;
                        ldapBindAuthenticationError = (LdapBindAuthenticationErrors)Convert.ToInt32(errorHexadecimal , 16);
                        return ldapBindAuthenticationError;
                    }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return LdapBindAuthenticationErrors.ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE;
    }
```

And these are your "LdapBindAuthenticationErrors", you can find more in MSDN, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
    internal enum LdapBindAuthenticationErrors
    {            
        OK = 0
        ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD = 0x56,
        ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION = 0x52D,
        ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE = 0x52e,
        ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION = 0x52f,
        ERROR_INVALID_LOGON_HOURS = 0x530,
        ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x532,
        ERROR_ACCOUNT_DISABLED = 0x533,
        ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXPIRED = 0x701,
        ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE = 0x773,
        ERROR_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT = 0x775
    }
```

Then you can use the return type of this Enum and do what you need with it in your controller.  The important thing to note, is that you're looking for the "data" piece of the string in the "Extended Error Message" of your `COMException` because this contains the almighty error code you are hunting for.

Good luck, and I hope this helps.  I tested it, and it works great for me.